# Create footer only on one page in Koma-script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, scrartcl

In the documentclass scrartcl, I’m creating a command to renew the header and footer mid-document.
The header should not show on the page on which the command is issued, but on all other pages.
This works very well using `\thispagestyle{plain}` (which drops the header but keeps the footer).
However, the footer should **only** show on the page on which the command is issued.
How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% only to remove page number for clarity of mwe
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}%
{
\rohead{New header on odd pages starts here}
\lehead{New header on even pages starts here}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lofoot*{Footer should only appear once, but appears on all odd pages}
}

\begin{document}
\mynewcommand
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lofoot*{<content>}` is a short version of `\lofoot[<content>]{<content>}`. It sets the footer content for both `plain` (optional argument) and `scrheadings` (mandantory argument) pages. If the footer on pages using page style `scrheadings` should be empty, use `\lofoot[<content>]{}`.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% only to remove page number for clarity of mwe
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}%
{
\rohead{New header on odd pages starts here}
\lehead{New header on even pages starts here}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lofoot[Footer should only appear once, but appears on all odd pages]{}% <- changed
}

\begin{document}
\mynewcommand
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had \lofoot[Test]{Test} before but didn’t think of emptying the curly braces...